# what the function of folder "tmp" in project play framework?

Tags: java, playframework

what the function of folder tmp?
when i create a project there is no folder tmp in my project. I just want to know for what is it? , iam using netbeans 7.3 and java programming language

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Play does not create a `tmp` folder and then you ask what this `tmp` folder is used for.

Comment: my application had an upload fiture. is that the cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tmp folder is where the play framework puts compiled classes. You can delete this folder (manually, or by executing the "play clean" command) and a new tmp folder will eventually be generated.